# JQuery functions are not working on web page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui

I have written a web application in ASP.net, Vs2010. This application has master page. That master page is applied to all pages. If I write some JQuery code on these pages, they don't work out. However if I shift that code to Site.Master Page, it starts working.
e.g. 
code mentioned below will not work on default.aspx, however it will work on Site.Master.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
```

Please let me know if anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

TA

Comment: In your web browser, when you View Source, is the javascript there?

Comment: What error message are you getting when it doesn't work?

Comment: I am not getting any error message as such. View Source is properly getting displayed as well.

Comment: Is any1 tried this? Please if anyone is using Jquery on child pages, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use firefox and firebug to check that all the scripts are loading as expected.

For the accordion to work you will need a script library reference for both jQuery and jQuery UI.

Also check that the element you are trying to apply the accordion to has an element id of "accordion" and not a class or something else along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have child pages in folder, you need to do something like this in your Master Page -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>' ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a load order issue have you tried it in with the ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%= accordion.ClientID %>").accordion();
```